# Any resources you know with regards to remotely reading data from arduino?

Tags: arduino-ide, wireless, remote-control

I am trying to implement arduino101 and my application needs to read data from the Arduino without a USB connection to my laptop. I appreciate you if you know any beginner-level tutorial for this.

Please let me know if you can't understand my question.

Comment: Just letting you know: I can't understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Bluetooth on the board, a Bluetooth dongle for your laptop if the laptop does not have bluetooth or you can buy a wifi shield.

The 101 has Bluetooth LE on the board.

You will find there is a Bluetooth -> Serial USB software, so the application on the laptop can still work the same way as when using the usb.

Here are the Bluetooth examples for the 101 on arduino.cc

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CurieBLE

and the user guide for the 101

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Arduino101